Everyday words for terminology











ARC
FACTOR
FREE
LOCAL


METRIC
MONSTER
NORMAL
PATH


POLAR
REGULAR
SCALAR
SIMPLE


SINGULAR
SUB
UNIFORM
VULGAR



Subtle Hint:

 (As contrary to one of the comments,) No category is about distributions.

Moderate Hint:

 (As contrary to another comment,) No category is about matrices.

Decisive Hint:

 SIMPLE doesn't belong to the category of groups.


rot13(V abgvprq erthyne, abezny naq zrgevp ner nyy cebcregvrf gb qrfpevor gbcbybtvpny fcnprf)

V qba'g xabj vs guvf vf hfrshy ohg vg frrzf yvxr znal jbeqf unir fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu znguf.

Gb nqq gb gur cerivbhf pbzzrag: serr, zbafgre, fvzcyr, naq fho ner nyy glcrf bs tebhcf

V abgvprq gung 'zbafgre tebhc, 'serr tebhc', 'snpgbe tebhc', 'fvzcyr tebhc' ner nyy grezvabybtvrf bs gur tebhc gurbel; naq 'erthyne qvfgevohgvba', 'havsbez qvfgevohgvba', 'abezny qvfgevohgvba', 'fvathyne qvfgevohgvba' ner nyy fbzr xvaq bs qvfgevohgvbaf bs gur cebonovyvgl gurbel

I've been secretly hoping it will turn out that none of the categories has anything to do with mathematics at all...

Here's my attempt. I think a few are shaky, but it's plausible.
First group:

 Groups! 
Free group 
Monster group 
Simple group 
Subgroup. This could also go with graph, but putting it here made the sizes work.

Second group:

 Graphs! 
Factor graph 
Local graph 
Path graph 
Regular graph

Third group:

 Spaces! 
Normal space 
Polar space 
Singular space. It's not a common term, but someone taught a whole class about it. 
 Vulgar space. This is the shakiest, but Isaac Newton distinguished between two different kinds of space: Absolute, true, mathematical space, and relative, common, vulgar space. See for instance Section 2 of this paper. This is more history and philosophy of physics than mathematics, but it was involved in Newton's work on calculus, so maybe it counts.

And finally:

 Pseudos! This is the shakiest theme, but it works pretty well. 
Pseudo-arc 
Pseudometric. This has a couple meanings, but it's pretty shaky, because this fits much better with space than it does here 
Pseudoscalar 
Pseudo-uniform: A type of polyhedron 


Amazing work Isaac bringing in calculus founder Isaac to help fit vulgar in.

Since no one has answered I will submit my answer, but something doesn't quite fit at the end so I don't think I'm fully correct.
Like other commenters, I first saw

 (monster, free, simple, sub) as "___ group" from abstract algebra

I didn't see this, but Lucenaposition pointed out

 (metric, normal, regular, local) as relating to topology

The next category I found is

 (path, uniform, arc, factor) as relating to graph theory, although these are not the first words I choose for graph theory so I'm a bit unsure on this one.

That leaves

 (polar, scalar, singular, vulgar) as relating to matrix theory??  I don't see how vulgar fits at all, and polar is a bit of a stretch, but the other two are certainly solid.


Personally I think local and uniform should be swapped because then the topology group consists of types of spaces (metric space, normal space, regular space, uniform space)

@BlazingSnow yes thanks for that correction.  Would (path, local, polar, singular) go with "integral" then?  That would leave factor, arc, scalar, vulgar.

I’m personally thinking types of matrices (path matrix, scalar matrix, singular matrix), and types of sets (arc set, factor set, polar set). The only issue is I’m unsure what to do about Local and Vulgar in that grouping

Yeah, vulgar is a real head scratcher.  It only goes in the category "___ fraction" as far as I can tell, but this category does not fit a single other word  Maybe there is a non-math category in there to throw us off? Like "vulgar, polar, regular, scalar" (ends in "ar") or something.
